# ubuntu + nginx + w3tc works fine except "rewrite url structure"

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I'm on ubuntu vps running nginx

Running wordpress with w3 total cache

Everything works fine except for when i enable "rewrite url structure" in w3tc, and it breaks, 404 probably to the minified files.

How to proceed?

Am i missing some package on my vps? what should I install?

Permalink for wordpress work fine though

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok fixed it

Due to some reason, w3tc wasn't creating the w3tc folder in wp-content

Created it and others with correct permissions and voila!